# javascript -I can't understand, why are the first two functions returning 'undefined' but the third one returns the desired value?

Tags: javascript, undefined, return-type

> **Addy(int c)** : function to add all the digits of the number and repeat the sum only if it is a single digit. Else, repeat the process
>   till it is a single number.

***first function :***

```
function addy(c) {
  c = parseInt(c);
  console.log('Recieved Number '+c);
  var sum;
  var nas = c.toString().split(''); // nas --> Number As String.
  console.log('Digits present in Number: '+nas);
  for (var i = 0; i < nas.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + parseInt(nas[i]);
  }
  console.log('Sum is: '+sum);
  if(sum < 9) {
    console.log(typeof sum);
    console.log('value of sum is: '+ sum);
    return sum;
  }
  console.log('Value Still not single digit.');
  addy(sum);
}
```

**Algorithm(that I used in the first function.):**

1. Convert the given number to string.
2. Get all the digits present in the numbers by using the split method on the string that has just been created from the number.
3. Loop through all the digits, and add to sum.
4. If the sum is single digit, then return and if it is not then repeat the process till the sum is single digit.

***Second function :***

```
  function addy(c){
     var s=0;
     while(c!==0)
     {
       s = s + parseInt(c%10);

       c = parseInt(c/10);
     }
     if(s>9)
     {
       s = addy(s);
     }
     else if(s<9)
     {
       return s;
     }
   }
```

***Third function :***
 (which actually works and is identical to the second function)

```
   function addy(num)
   {
    var sum = 0;

    while (num > 0)
   {
      sum += parseInt(num % 10);

      num = parseInt(num / 10);
   }
   if (sum > 9)
   {
      sum = addy(sum);
   }
     return sum;
   }
```

> I want to know the reason why the first two functions are returning "undefined" instead of returning a single digit number.

Comment: third is not identical to the second function

Comment: What do your `console.log`s show?

Comment: The logic applied in second and third function is same. ( What i actually meant ! )

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **your third function is *not* identical to your second function**.

**First function**

Fixed code:

```js
function addy(c) {
  c = parseInt(c);
  var sum = 0; // <------- THIS LINE
  var nas = c.toString().split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < nas.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + parseInt(nas[i]);
  }
  if(sum < 9) {
    return sum;
  }
  addy(sum);
}
console.log(addy(123));
```

Your original code has a line:

```
var sum;  // sum is undefined
```

Therefore, when the execution reaches this line:

```
sum = sum + parseInt(nas[i]);
```

`sum` will become `NaN` because that translate to:

```
undefined = undefined + parseInt(nas[i]);
```

To make it work, you simply need to initialise the value of `sum`:

```
var sum = 0;   // Give sum a default value;
```

**Second function**

Fixed code:

```js
function addy(c){
  var s=0;
  while(c!==0)
  {
   s = s + parseInt(c%10);
   c = parseInt(c/10);
  }
  if(s>9)
  {
   s = addy(s);
   return s;     // <----- THIS LINE
  }
  else
  {
   return s;
  }
}
console.log(addy(1234));
```

In original code:

```
if(s>9)
{
  s = addy(s);
}
else
{
  return s;
}
```

Nothing is being returned if `s > 9`. Therefore you get `undefined`.

To make it work, you simply need to add a `return` line:

```
if (s > 9){
    s = addy(s);
    return s;    // <--- THIS LINE
} else {
    return s;
}
```